# Difference between FileUpload Class and FileUpload Control in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I read the MSDN pages on the FileUpload Class and the FileUpload Control, but I don't completely understand them. I know they are both used for uploading files, and I understand how the Control would work, but what would determine which one I use for uploading a file, and what's the main difference? Does the FileUpload Control use the Class to upload the file to the server?

**Refrences:**

msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227677.aspx

msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227669.aspx

msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FileUpload Class:**

Displays a text box control and a browse button that enable users to select a file to upload to the server.

```
Namespace:   System.Web.UI.WebControls
Assembly:  System.Web (in System.Web.dll)
```

The FileUpload class is derived from the WebControl class, and inherits all its members. Apart from those, the FileUpload class has the following read-only properties:

---

**Properties**  **Description**

1. FileBytes : Returns an array of the bytes in a file to be uploaded.
2. FileContent Returns the stream object pointing to the file to be
   uploaded.
3. FileName    Returns the name of the file to be uploaded.
4. HasFile Specifies whether the control has a file to upload.
5. PostedFile  Returns a reference to the uploaded file.

**FileUpload Control:**

The FileUpload control allows the user to browse for and select the file to be uploaded, providing a browse button and a text box for entering the filename.

Once, the user has entered the filename in the text box by typing the name or browsing, the SaveAs method of the FileUpload control can be called to save the file to the disk.

The basic syntax of FileUpload is:

```html
<asp:FileUpload ID= "Uploader" runat = "server" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the links you provided it looks like they are the same.  In fact the first link, has a link to the third link at the bottom.

All Controls are Classes.  You will see on the last link that there is a class hierarchy, which shows it derives from:

1. System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl
2. System.Web.UI.Control
3. System.Object

Comment: I noticed that there is a class hierarchy, but on the C# code example for FileUpload Class, it shows that class FileUpload inherits WebControl, but the code for FileUpload Control shows the Page_Load method and it only uploads the file if its a postback. I am confused about the two because, as you mentioned, Controls are Classes; so I was wondering if the FileUpload Control just uses the FileUpload Class to implement the upload?

Answer (score 0):

`FileUpload` control is simply a control for you to select a file, but it's not a class to be used for uploading the file.

`FileUpload` class is a class of the `FileUpload` control, as what your given links discuss, All controls are Classes, which applies to your question.  FileUpload class will be used for you to change properties of `FileUpload` control. Or how you're going to manipulate the control from code behind.

Just to clarify, `FileUpload` control is just a control for you to select a file. But for uploading the file itself, you're going to use streaming, or depending on how you're going to upload the file to the back-end of your project.